# How to add an email group to Google Play Store Alpha/Beta Testing

Tags: google-play, google-apps

I'm trying to add a Google Group from my domain to the list of Beta testers on Google Play for an app I've developed.

My domain is "mydomain", and runs Google Apps. I have created a group a few days ago on the admin console. The group is called customer-beta@mydomain. I am logged in as richard@mydomain, and am owner and member of that group, as well as administrator of mydomain.

When I attempt to add the group to the beta, it says "To select a group from a Google Apps Domain you need to be logged in with an account in the domain". As far as I can tell, I am logged in with an account in the domain.

I can add @googlegroups.com groups, but this seems somewhat less than ideal.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

[image: Screen shot of play store highlighting error]

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This may be the answer to why this is not working:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992

It appears that the owner of your Developer Console must also be a member of your Google Apps Domain.

"The publisher account owner who registered with the Android Developer Console must be a Google Apps user in the same domain, such as internal IT staff, and not external developers."